# Illness and plants

Tags: nouns

Can I use the word "illness" when it comes to plants? I've never heard of a plant having an "illness" only a "disease" but another editor doubts this. I can't find a credible source to prove which one is correct or not. I also can't find any sentences of "plants" and "illness" on the web which leads me to believe my gut is correct. But a credible source would be helpful if anyone can recommend one, I'd appreciate it!
Thanks,
E

Comment: Sickness? a plant is sick or a sick plant.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/illness#etymonline_v_34449 looks like illness has moral roots

Answer (score 1):

*Can I use the word "illness" when it comes to plants?* Yes it appears so.

**A study shows the efficiency of composts of agro-industrial waste to reduce **illnesses** of the plants**  [Horticulture](http://www.interempresas.net/Horticola/Articulos/63125-estudio-muestra-eficacia-composts-residuos-agroindustriales-reducir-enfermedades-plantas.html) 2012

and

**American Journal of Pharmacy** 1923  [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=mGwXAQAAIAAJ&lpg=PA117&ots=CydHm4HmAK&dq=%22illnesses%20of%20plants%22&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q=%22illnesses%20of%20plants%22&f=false)

> ... has discovered that many **illnesses** of plants, similarly to those
>   of people, are due to these microscopic animal parasites.

**Management and Applications of Complex Systems** - Page 143 [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=YtWMDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA143&dq=%22illnesses%20of%20plants%22&pg=PA143#v=onepage&q=%22illnesses%20of%20plants%22&f=false) 2019!

> The content of the knowledge base includes the following: types of
>   soils, sorts of wheat, classes of machines and mechanisms, **illnesses
>   of plants**, insects, pesticides, fertilizers, etc.

Plant **diseases** is more common but plants can have **illnesses** too.